# What happens when a Transform stream is paused?

Tags: node.js, stream

If you have a flowing readable stream piped into a Transform stream (for instance stream.PassThrough), what happens if you pause the duplex stream? Will it pause the original readable stream as well? If not, does the stream data coming from the readable stream "leak out"? Or does the data accumulate somewhere in program memory?

**EDIT** Apparently, the readable stream should indeed pause. However, there seems to be a delay before the pause.
In the repl:

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.5.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const fs = require('fs');
undefined
> const stream = require('stream');
undefined
> const transform = new stream.PassThrough();
undefined
> const readable = fs.createReadStream('yes.jpg');
undefined
> readable.readableFlowing;
null
> readable.on('data', console.log);
  console.log(readable.readableFlowing);
  console.log(readable.isPaused());
  readable.pipe(transform);
  console.log(readable.readableFlowing);
  console.log(readable.isPaused());
true
false
true
false
undefined
> <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 00 22 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 01 01 12 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 02 01 01 02 01 01 02 ... 65486 more bytes>
<Buffer f2 5b ab 7d ff 00 bd 5c 15 6a 46 99 b4 70 bc de fc 4f 9c 2e 63 b7 d6 13 6c 2a ab 54 74 7b 35 d2 f5 56 5b 85 5f f8 15 49 6d a7 c9 e1 f7 89 a6 68 b6 a3 ... 65486 more bytes>
> readable.isPaused();
true
> readable.readableEnded;
false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what happens if you pause the duplex stream? Will it pause the original readable stream as well?

Yes, it will pause any other streams in the chain.  When streams are piped together or when one is a properly implemented transform, they implement flow control so nobody is forced to buffer more than they want.  This is one of the nice features of using piped/transform streams (they automatically do flow control).

But, all `.pipe()` does is register some event handlers. Those event handlers don't actually get any events until your block of code finishes executing statements and returns back to the event loop. So, your large block of code that starts with `readable.on()` runs in its entirety before any events run from either the `readaonble.on('data', ...)` or from the `readable.pipe()`.

Comment: [REPL output](https://i.imgur.com/d9E61P5.png) What's happening here? Is there a delay between the pipe and the time the stream is actually paused?

Comment: @TahaAhmed - Please put the relevant code into your question, formatted properly one statement per line.  Can't read your code in the repl very easily and can't copy portions of it into an answer and it won't get indexed for searching.

Comment: @TahaAhmed - All `.pipe()` does is register some event handlers.  Those event handlers don't actually get any events until your block of code finishes executing statements and returns back to the event loop.  So, your large block of code that starts with `readable.on()` runs in its entirety before any events run from either the `readaonble.on('data', ...)` or from the `readable.pipe()`.

Comment: But `.on()` quite literally attaches an event handler, does the Readable class override this method?

Comment: @TahaAhmed - Yeah, that's what I said.  All it does is attach an event handler.  Same with `.pipe()`.  You end up with two event handlers for the same `data` event (one in your `.on('data', ...)` and one inside of `.pipe()`) that each see the same data.  You don't seem to understand that you call `readable.on()`, then you call `readable.pipe()`, then some time LATER, those events start running and calling those event handlers.  So, both your `console.log(readable.isPaused());` occur BEFORE any events actually fire.